# Entity Framework 4 Table Valued Function

Tags: entity-framework

I am aware that table valued functions are not supported in previous versions of entity framework. I was wondering if this is now supported in EF 4? I cant see my functions in the edm designer so i'm guessing they are not supported unless I am doing something wrong?

If they are not supported is there a workaround? My table valued function takes a single parameter.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can definitely use Table-Valued functions with EF. Here's a great link on how this can be achieved: http://blog.ondrejsv.com/post/Using-table-valued-database-functions-with-Entity-Framework-40.aspx#comment

Comment: Really a savior. I was doing it in VS 2010 and struggled for half an hour before realizing the fact that it is not at all supported by the designer. The query EF model designer fires internally to know about available DB objects was a good catch! Made my day.

Answer (score 3):

It appears as you can use them...

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/efdesign/model-defined-functions)

It uses the GetFriends() table valued function. Still i don't really know how to use it.